# Convert city-based time zone in .Net

Tags: .net, timezone

Such city-based time zones (or whatever you call this) as `Asia/Shanghai`, `America/Los_Angeles` are widely used in PHP and Java, for example,

```
java.util.TimeZone.TimeZone timeZoneNewYork = java.util.TimeZone.TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
```

As far as I know, .Net uses a different key to get the corresponding time zone, for `America/New_York` it's `Eastern Standard Time`

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfoNewYork = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
```

If I have a city-based time zone string, e.g. `"America/New_York"`, how can I convert it to the right time zone in .Net, `TimeZoneInfo{Eastern Standard Time}`

Comment: Does this help? http://citytimezones.info/

Comment: Yes, it does... but I think there is supposed to be some easier way

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to translate between Windows and IANA time zones?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348807/how-to-translate-between-windows-and-iana-time-zones)

Answer (score 1):

Those are IANA/Olson time zone identifiers, and they are much more universal than the Windows time zones that .Net uses.  Read the "Time Zone Databases" section of the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

There are several libraries that you can use to work with these in .Net, but the best one IMHO is [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/).  With this library, you won't *need* to use `TimeZoneInfo` at all.

### Update

[I have posted conversion functions here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17348807/634824).