# Javascript equlivent to .Net TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

In .Net I can use the following to figure out what time it is in a specified timezone:

```
var targetDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, "Atlantic Standard Time");
```

I've been trying to figure out a way to do this in Javascript, but so far no luck. I was able to find the following: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/ which has some details, if I can specify an offset, but I cant seem to figure out how to get that from a specified timezone (from the currentTimezone its as easy as `myDate.getTimezoneOffset()`).

Again in .Net I could do this with:

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Atlantic Standard Time");
TimeSpan offset = tzi.GetUtcOffset( myDateTime);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript can't do this natively.  You'll need a library.  I provided a list of several different libraries for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824).

Also recognize that "Atlantic Standard Time" is a Microsoft time zone identifier.  You need to use the equivalent IANA time zone, which would be "America/Halifax".  You can read more in the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), under "Time Zone Databases".  If you need to convert from Microsoft identifiers, you'll have to do that in your .NET code, using Noda Time, as I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17348807/634824).

Here is an example of using [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/):

*(intentionally split into separate statements for readability)*

```
var now = moment();
var atlantic = now.tz("America/Halifax");
var s = atlantic.format();
```