# Powershell: How to reload Windows System Time info during session?

Tags: windows, datetime, powershell, timezone

Having some issues with my script. The endgame here is to set the Windows system time, then convert the timezone into a UTC offset to import into MySQL and set the time zone there as well.

The issue is that the server is set to 00:00 by default. When $timezone = "Eastern Standard Time", I run these commands, and $offset returns 00:00 still, instead of -05:00 . $time also reflects 00:00. If I open a new PS window and run the $time= line, I get the correct value; however, I need to do this in the initial window. Thanks in advance.

```
tzutil /s $timezone;

$time = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local|select -expandproperty BaseUtcOffset;
$DateParts = ([string]$time).split(":");
$offset = ($DateParts[0]+":"+$DateParts[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to reload the System Time in the current session, it may be simpler to just use `tzutil` again to reliably retrieve the newly updated system time.

Here's an example where we get all system time zones, and then filter on the output of `tzutil /g` where the ID of the time zone matches our current system timezone. You'll want to do something like this since the current session doesn't know about the change.

Example:

```
PS C:\> $timezone = "Eastern Standard Time"
PS C:\> tzutil /s $timezone
PS C:\> [System.TimeZoneInfo]::GetSystemTimeZones() | where { $_.ID -like (tzutil /g) }

Id                         : Eastern Standard Time
DisplayName                : (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
StandardName               : Eastern Standard Time
DaylightName               : Eastern Daylight Time
BaseUtcOffset              : -05:00:00
SupportsDaylightSavingTime : True
```

From there, you can extract the offset from the `BaseUtcOffset` property as you did before.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a good idea.  The Windows identifier "Eastern Standard Time" is the lookup key for the US Eastern time zone, which is composed of both Eastern Standard Time AND Eastern Daylight Time.  Passing -5:00 is only valid during the standard time.  You would need to get -4:00 during daylight time.

MySQL uses IANA/Olson time zone identifiers.  Instead of "Eastern Standard Time", you would pass "America/New_York".  There are conversions provided by the [Unicode CLDR](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml), which you could do in .Net (and maybe Powershell) using Noda Time, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17348807/634824).

But all of this is oveverkill.  You don't need to tell MySQL to change it's time zone unless you want to *deviate* from the system time zone.  Review [the docs for MySQL time zone support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html).  It is clear that you can just pass `SYSTEM` and it will use the system's time zone.  This is actually the *default* so you probably don't need to do anything at all.