# CSOM Sharepoint current user timezone

Tags: timezone, csom

I need to get the TimeZone and its Bias for the current user in CSOM.
If I read the siteuserinfolist for my current user, I get a TimeZone field with a ushort ID.
is SSOM, I can use SPRegionalSettings with this ID
is CSOM, TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones uses a String ID (like the timezone title !) 
Any idea how I can get the Bias of the current user in CSOM ?
THANKS !

Comment: If by "bias" you mean the time zone offset, recognize that you can only get an offset for a specific date.  You can get the *current* offset, but you can't expect that to be fixed, as the offset will change as DST comes and goes.

Comment: Also, you may find the CSV mapping I created in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22395498/634824) to be useful.  You won't need the IANA TZ name, but rather you would use the "SharePoint ID" and "Windows ID" columns only.