# how to get TimeZone object in java from zone names like "(GMT+10:00) Brisbane" OR "(GMT+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris"

Tags: java, timezone, timezone-offset

I am able to get Timezone object in java from full string name "Australia/Brisbane"

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Brisbane");
```

How to get java.util.TimeZone from zone names like
"(GMT+10:00) Brisbane" OR
"(GMT) Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London" OR
"(GMT+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris" OR
"(GMT-09:00) Alaska"

Above zone name strings which i need to convert into TimeZone object are from windows 10 >> "Date and Time Settings" >> "Time Zone" dropdown.

Comment: They don't look standard so you will probably need to parse them manually...

Comment: Perhaps you're after something like this method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-

Comment: Possibly related (though asking about PHP): [Olson time zone to windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466101/olson-time-zone-to-windows).

Comment: The samples in the question appear to match those in [this Microsoft list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/973627/microsoft-time-zone-index-values), which you can also see on a Windows PC in Settings > Time and Language > Time zone.

Comment: @andrewjames - That list is static and from Windows Embedded 1.1 which is long expired.  Please don't use it as a reference.  It's not current or maintained.  The current list can be obtained on Windows using `tzutil /L`

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint - much better, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Strings like `"(GMT+10:00) Brisbane"` are ***display names***.  They are resource strings intended for human readability and are localized to a specific language (English in this case).  They can, and do, change over time as necessary.  They will be different when localized for other languages.

From the ones you gave, they like originate from Windows but they aren't exactly the current set from English editions of Windows 10.  Possibly they came from older versions of Windows, but you should verify that yourself.

By contrast, `"Australia/Brisbane"` is an [IANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority) time zone identifier.  It is exactly that string, and doesn't change by language (even if other languages had spelling or symbol variations).  They are intended for programmatic identification, such as by passing to the `getTimeZone` API you showed.

[IANA time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) are the primary identifiers used in Java.  Windows has its own set.  The equivalent Windows identifier is `"E. Australia Standard Time"` - which again is exactly that string, regardless of language.

The [Unicode Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository) project maintains the canonical mapping between the two sets of identifiers in the [`windowsZones.xml`](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/master/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml) file.  It also includes the current English Windows display names as comments to assist with reading the file.

**In short:** I don't recommend mapping display names as they are localized and can change.  Use identifiers instead.

Answer (score 2):

[The Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63817320/642706) by Matt Johnson-Pint is correct and wise.

In addition, here is some example code for managing a [list of time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Java comes bundled with a copy of the [*tzdata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) defining the current list of names.

Over time, the names of time zones can change. For example, `Asia/Calcutta` is now deprecated, and aliased to `Asia/Kolkata`. And some new zone may be added. The rules for each zone change, more often than you might realize. So it is important to keep the tzdata up-to-date. If some zone you care about is changing with little forewarning, which unfortunately is happening all too often, you may need to manually update the tzdata file in Java, in your database system such as Postgres, and in your host OS (depending on your needs). Regular updates to your JDK will likely come with a recent version of the tzdata.

One other thing: [`java.util.TimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html) class is now legacy, replaced by [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) and [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) in the modern *java.time* classes. The troublesome old date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

You can ask `ZoneId` for a `Set` of the time zone identifiers defined in the bundled *tzdata` file.

```
Set < String > timeZoneIdentifiers = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
```

```
timeZoneIdentifiers.toString(): 
[Asia/Aden, America/Cuiaba, Etc/GMT+9, Etc/GMT+8, Africa/Nairobi, America/Marigot, Asia/Aqtau, Pacific/Kwajalein, America/El_Salvador, Asia/Pontianak, Africa/Cairo, Pacific/Pago_Pago, Africa/Mbabane, Asia/Kuching, Pacific/Honolulu, Pacific/Rarotonga, America/Guatemala, Australia/Hobart, Europe/London, America/Belize, America/Panama, Asia/Chungking, America/Managua, America/Indiana/Petersburg, Asia/Yerevan, Europe/Brussels, GMT, Europe/Warsaw, America/Chicago, Asia/Kashgar, Chile/Continental, Pacific/Yap, CET, Etc/GMT-1, Etc/GMT-0, Europe/Jersey, America/Tegucigalpa, Etc/GMT-5, Europe/Istanbul, America/Eirunepe, Etc/GMT-4, America/Miquelon, Etc/GMT-3, Europe/Luxembourg, Etc/GMT-2, Etc/GMT-9, America/Argentina/Catamarca, Etc/GMT-8, Etc/GMT-7, Etc/GMT-6, Europe/Zaporozhye, Canada/Yukon, Canada/Atlantic, Atlantic/St_Helena, Australia/Tasmania, Libya, Europe/Guernsey, America/Grand_Turk, Asia/Samarkand, America/Argentina/Cordoba, Asia/Phnom_Penh, Africa/Kigali, Asia/Almaty, US/Alaska, Asia/Dubai, Europe/Isle_of_Man, America/Araguaina, Cuba, Asia/Novosibirsk, America/Argentina/Salta, Etc/GMT+3, Africa/Tunis, Etc/GMT+2, Etc/GMT+1, Pacific/Fakaofo, Africa/Tripoli, Etc/GMT+0, Israel, Africa/Banjul, Etc/GMT+7, Indian/Comoro, Etc/GMT+6, Etc/GMT+5, Etc/GMT+4, Pacific/Port_Moresby, US/Arizona, Antarctica/Syowa, Indian/Reunion, Pacific/Palau, Europe/Kaliningrad, America/Montevideo, Africa/Windhoek, Asia/Karachi, Africa/Mogadishu, Australia/Perth, Brazil/East, Etc/GMT, Asia/Chita, Pacific/Easter, Antarctica/Davis, Antarctica/McMurdo, Asia/Macao, America/Manaus, Africa/Freetown, Europe/Bucharest, Asia/Tomsk, America/Argentina/Mendoza, Asia/Macau, Europe/Malta, Mexico/BajaSur, Pacific/Tahiti, Africa/Asmera, Europe/Busingen, America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos, Africa/Malabo, Europe/Skopje, America/Catamarca, America/Godthab, Europe/Sarajevo, Australia/ACT, GB-Eire, Africa/Lagos, America/Cordoba, Europe/Rome, Asia/Dacca, Indian/Mauritius, Pacific/Samoa, America/Regina, America/Fort_Wayne, America/Dawson_Creek, Africa/Algiers, Europe/Mariehamn, America/St_Johns, America/St_Thomas, Europe/Zurich, America/Anguilla, Asia/Dili, America/Denver, Africa/Bamako, Europe/Saratov, GB, Mexico/General, Pacific/Wallis, Europe/Gibraltar, Africa/Conakry, Africa/Lubumbashi, Asia/Istanbul, America/Havana, NZ-CHAT, Asia/Choibalsan, America/Porto_Acre, Asia/Omsk, Europe/Vaduz, US/Michigan, Asia/Dhaka, America/Barbados, Europe/Tiraspol, Atlantic/Cape_Verde, Asia/Yekaterinburg, America/Louisville, Pacific/Johnston, Pacific/Chatham, Europe/Ljubljana, America/Sao_Paulo, Asia/Jayapura, America/Curacao, Asia/Dushanbe, America/Guyana, America/Guayaquil, America/Martinique, Portugal, Europe/Berlin, Europe/Moscow, Europe/Chisinau, America/Puerto_Rico, America/Rankin_Inlet, Pacific/Ponape, Europe/Stockholm, Europe/Budapest, America/Argentina/Jujuy, Australia/Eucla, Asia/Shanghai, Universal, Europe/Zagreb, America/Port_of_Spain, Europe/Helsinki, Asia/Beirut, Asia/Tel_Aviv, Pacific/Bougainville, US/Central, Africa/Sao_Tome, Indian/Chagos, America/Cayenne, Asia/Yakutsk, Pacific/Galapagos, Australia/North, Europe/Paris, Africa/Ndjamena, Pacific/Fiji, America/Rainy_River, Indian/Maldives, Australia/Yancowinna, SystemV/AST4, Asia/Oral, America/Yellowknife, Pacific/Enderbury, America/Juneau, Australia/Victoria, America/Indiana/Vevay, Asia/Tashkent, Asia/Jakarta, Africa/Ceuta, Asia/Barnaul, America/Recife, America/Buenos_Aires, America/Noronha, America/Swift_Current, Australia/Adelaide, America/Metlakatla, Africa/Djibouti, America/Paramaribo, Asia/Qostanay, Europe/Simferopol, Europe/Sofia, Africa/Nouakchott, Europe/Prague, America/Indiana/Vincennes, Antarctica/Mawson, America/Kralendijk, Antarctica/Troll, Europe/Samara, Indian/Christmas, America/Antigua, Pacific/Gambier, America/Indianapolis, America/Inuvik, America/Iqaluit, Pacific/Funafuti, UTC, Antarctica/Macquarie, Canada/Pacific, America/Moncton, Africa/Gaborone, Pacific/Chuuk, Asia/Pyongyang, America/St_Vincent, Asia/Gaza, Etc/Universal, PST8PDT, Atlantic/Faeroe, Asia/Qyzylorda, Canada/Newfoundland, America/Kentucky/Louisville, America/Yakutat, Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh, Antarctica/Casey, Europe/Copenhagen, Africa/Asmara, Atlantic/Azores, Europe/Vienna, ROK, Pacific/Pitcairn, America/Mazatlan, Australia/Queensland, Pacific/Nauru, Europe/Tirane, Asia/Kolkata, SystemV/MST7, Australia/Canberra, MET, Australia/Broken_Hill, Europe/Riga, America/Dominica, Africa/Abidjan, America/Mendoza, America/Santarem, Kwajalein, America/Asuncion, Asia/Ulan_Bator, NZ, America/Boise, Australia/Currie, EST5EDT, Pacific/Guam, Pacific/Wake, Atlantic/Bermuda, America/Costa_Rica, America/Dawson, Asia/Chongqing, Eire, Europe/Amsterdam, America/Indiana/Knox, America/North_Dakota/Beulah, Africa/Accra, Atlantic/Faroe, Mexico/BajaNorte, America/Maceio, Etc/UCT, Pacific/Apia, GMT0, America/Atka, Pacific/Niue, Australia/Lord_Howe, Europe/Dublin, Pacific/Truk, MST7MDT, America/Monterrey, America/Nassau, America/Jamaica, Asia/Bishkek, America/Atikokan, Atlantic/Stanley, Australia/NSW, US/Hawaii, SystemV/CST6, Indian/Mahe, Asia/Aqtobe, America/Sitka, Asia/Vladivostok, Africa/Libreville, Africa/Maputo, Zulu, America/Kentucky/Monticello, Africa/El_Aaiun, Africa/Ouagadougou, America/Coral_Harbour, Pacific/Marquesas, Brazil/West, America/Aruba, America/North_Dakota/Center, America/Cayman, Asia/Ulaanbaatar, Asia/Baghdad, Europe/San_Marino, America/Indiana/Tell_City, America/Tijuana, Pacific/Saipan, SystemV/YST9, Africa/Douala, America/Chihuahua, America/Ojinaga, Asia/Hovd, America/Anchorage, Chile/EasterIsland, America/Halifax, Antarctica/Rothera, America/Indiana/Indianapolis, US/Mountain, Asia/Damascus, America/Argentina/San_Luis, America/Santiago, Asia/Baku, America/Argentina/Ushuaia, Atlantic/Reykjavik, Africa/Brazzaville, Africa/Porto-Novo, America/La_Paz, Antarctica/DumontDUrville, Asia/Taipei, Antarctica/South_Pole, Asia/Manila, Asia/Bangkok, Africa/Dar_es_Salaam, Poland, Atlantic/Madeira, Antarctica/Palmer, America/Thunder_Bay, Africa/Addis_Ababa, Asia/Yangon, Europe/Uzhgorod, Brazil/DeNoronha, Asia/Ashkhabad, Etc/Zulu, America/Indiana/Marengo, America/Creston, America/Punta_Arenas, America/Mexico_City, Antarctica/Vostok, Asia/Jerusalem, Europe/Andorra, US/Samoa, PRC, Asia/Vientiane, Pacific/Kiritimati, America/Matamoros, America/Blanc-Sablon, Asia/Riyadh, Iceland, Pacific/Pohnpei, Asia/Ujung_Pandang, Atlantic/South_Georgia, Europe/Lisbon, Asia/Harbin, Europe/Oslo, Asia/Novokuznetsk, CST6CDT, Atlantic/Canary, America/Knox_IN, Asia/Kuwait, SystemV/HST10, Pacific/Efate, Africa/Lome, America/Bogota, America/Menominee, America/Adak, Pacific/Norfolk, Europe/Kirov, America/Resolute, Pacific/Tarawa, Africa/Kampala, Asia/Krasnoyarsk, Greenwich, SystemV/EST5, America/Edmonton, Europe/Podgorica, Australia/South, Canada/Central, Africa/Bujumbura, America/Santo_Domingo, US/Eastern, Europe/Minsk, Pacific/Auckland, Africa/Casablanca, America/Glace_Bay, Canada/Eastern, Asia/Qatar, Europe/Kiev, Singapore, Asia/Magadan, SystemV/PST8, America/Port-au-Prince, Europe/Belfast, America/St_Barthelemy, Asia/Ashgabat, Africa/Luanda, America/Nipigon, Atlantic/Jan_Mayen, Brazil/Acre, Asia/Muscat, Asia/Bahrain, Europe/Vilnius, America/Fortaleza, Etc/GMT0, US/East-Indiana, America/Hermosillo, America/Cancun, Africa/Maseru, Pacific/Kosrae, Africa/Kinshasa, Asia/Kathmandu, Asia/Seoul, Australia/Sydney, America/Lima, Australia/LHI, America/St_Lucia, Europe/Madrid, America/Bahia_Banderas, America/Montserrat, Asia/Brunei, America/Santa_Isabel, Canada/Mountain, America/Cambridge_Bay, Asia/Colombo, Australia/West, Indian/Antananarivo, Australia/Brisbane, Indian/Mayotte, US/Indiana-Starke, Asia/Urumqi, US/Aleutian, Europe/Volgograd, America/Lower_Princes, America/Vancouver, Africa/Blantyre, America/Rio_Branco, America/Danmarkshavn, America/Detroit, America/Thule, Africa/Lusaka, Asia/Hong_Kong, Iran, America/Argentina/La_Rioja, Africa/Dakar, SystemV/CST6CDT, America/Tortola, America/Porto_Velho, Asia/Sakhalin, Etc/GMT+10, America/Scoresbysund, Asia/Kamchatka, Asia/Thimbu, Africa/Harare, Etc/GMT+12, Etc/GMT+11, Navajo, America/Nome, Europe/Tallinn, Turkey, Africa/Khartoum, Africa/Johannesburg, Africa/Bangui, Europe/Belgrade, Jamaica, Africa/Bissau, Asia/Tehran, WET, Europe/Astrakhan, Africa/Juba, America/Campo_Grande, America/Belem, Etc/Greenwich, Asia/Saigon, America/Ensenada, Pacific/Midway, America/Jujuy, Africa/Timbuktu, America/Bahia, America/Goose_Bay, America/Virgin, America/Pangnirtung, Asia/Katmandu, America/Phoenix, Africa/Niamey, America/Whitehorse, Pacific/Noumea, Asia/Tbilisi, America/Montreal, Asia/Makassar, America/Argentina/San_Juan, Hongkong, UCT, Asia/Nicosia, America/Indiana/Winamac, SystemV/MST7MDT, America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia, America/Boa_Vista, America/Grenada, Asia/Atyrau, Australia/Darwin, Asia/Khandyga, Asia/Kuala_Lumpur, Asia/Famagusta, Asia/Thimphu, Asia/Rangoon, Europe/Bratislava, Asia/Calcutta, America/Argentina/Tucuman, Asia/Kabul, Indian/Cocos, Japan, Pacific/Tongatapu, America/New_York, Etc/GMT-12, Etc/GMT-11, America/Nuuk, Etc/GMT-10, SystemV/YST9YDT, Europe/Ulyanovsk, Etc/GMT-14, Etc/GMT-13, W-SU, America/Merida, EET, America/Rosario, Canada/Saskatchewan, America/St_Kitts, Arctic/Longyearbyen, America/Fort_Nelson, America/Caracas, America/Guadeloupe, Asia/Hebron, Indian/Kerguelen, SystemV/PST8PDT, Africa/Monrovia, Asia/Ust-Nera, Egypt, Asia/Srednekolymsk, America/North_Dakota/New_Salem, Asia/Anadyr, Australia/Melbourne, Asia/Irkutsk, America/Shiprock, America/Winnipeg, Europe/Vatican, Asia/Amman, Etc/UTC, SystemV/AST4ADT, Asia/Tokyo, America/Toronto, Asia/Singapore, Australia/Lindeman, America/Los_Angeles, SystemV/EST5EDT, Pacific/Majuro, America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires, Europe/Nicosia, Pacific/Guadalcanal, Europe/Athens, US/Pacific, Europe/Monaco]
```

As discussed in the other Answer, the time zone identifiers should be used within your own code for tracking each time zone. But for the user interface, you should localize the name of the zone into the language and cultural norms of each particular user.

For each identifier, we can instantiate a `ZoneId` object, and interrogate that object for the automatically-localized name of that time zone. We specify a `Locale` object to determine (a) the human language to use in translation, and (b) the cultural norms to use in formatting, capitalization, abbreviation, etc.

```java
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;
for ( String timeZoneIdentifier : timeZoneIdentifiers )
{
    ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( timeZoneIdentifier );
    String output = z.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , locale );
    System.out.println( z + " ➙ " + output );
}
```

When run:

```
Asia/Aden ➙ heure de l’Arabie
America/Cuiaba ➙ heure de l’Amazonie
Etc/GMT+9 ➙ UTC−09:00
Etc/GMT+8 ➙ UTC−08:00
Africa/Nairobi ➙ Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
America/Marigot ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
Asia/Aqtau ➙ Heure d'Aqtau
Pacific/Kwajalein ➙ Heure des Iles Marshall
America/El_Salvador ➙ heure du Centre
Asia/Pontianak ➙ Heure de l'Indonésie occidentale
Africa/Cairo ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Est
Pacific/Pago_Pago ➙ heure des Samoa
Africa/Mbabane ➙ Afrique du Sud
Asia/Kuching ➙ Heure de Malaisie
Pacific/Honolulu ➙ heure d’Hawaï-Aléoutiennes
Pacific/Rarotonga ➙ heure des îles Cook
America/Guatemala ➙ heure du Centre
Australia/Hobart ➙ heure de l’Est de l’Australie
Europe/London ➙ Heure britannique
America/Belize ➙ heure du Centre
America/Panama ➙ heure de l’Est
Asia/Chungking ➙ heure de Chine
America/Managua ➙ heure du Centre
America/Indiana/Petersburg ➙ heure de l’Est
Asia/Yerevan ➙ heure de l’Arménie
Europe/Brussels ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
GMT ➙ Heure de Greenwich
Europe/Warsaw ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
America/Chicago ➙ heure du Centre
Asia/Kashgar ➙ Chine
Chile/Continental ➙ heure du Chili
Pacific/Yap ➙ Heure de Chuuk
CET ➙ Heure d'Europe centrale
Etc/GMT-1 ➙ UTC+01:00
Etc/GMT-0 ➙ heure moyenne de Greenwich
Europe/Jersey ➙ Heure britannique
America/Tegucigalpa ➙ heure du Centre
Etc/GMT-5 ➙ UTC+05:00
Europe/Istanbul ➙ Heure d'Europe de l'Est
America/Eirunepe ➙ heure de l’Acre
Etc/GMT-4 ➙ UTC+04:00
America/Miquelon ➙ heure de Saint-Pierre-et-Miquelon
Etc/GMT-3 ➙ UTC+03:00
Europe/Luxembourg ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
Etc/GMT-2 ➙ UTC+02:00
Etc/GMT-9 ➙ UTC+09:00
America/Argentina/Catamarca ➙ heure de l’Argentine
Etc/GMT-8 ➙ UTC+08:00
Etc/GMT-7 ➙ UTC+07:00
Etc/GMT-6 ➙ UTC+06:00
Europe/Zaporozhye ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Est
Canada/Yukon ➙ heure du Pacifique
Canada/Atlantic ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
Atlantic/St_Helena ➙ Heure de Greenwich
Australia/Tasmania ➙ heure de l’Est de l’Australie
Libya ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Est
Europe/Guernsey ➙ Heure britannique
America/Grand_Turk ➙ heure de l’Est
Asia/Samarkand ➙ heure de l’Ouzbékistan
America/Argentina/Cordoba ➙ heure de l’Argentine
Asia/Phnom_Penh ➙ Heure d'Indochine
Africa/Kigali ➙ Heure d'Afrique centrale
Asia/Almaty ➙ Heure d'Alma-Ata
US/Alaska ➙ heure de l’Alaska
Asia/Dubai ➙ Golfe
Europe/Isle_of_Man ➙ Heure britannique
America/Araguaina ➙ heure de Brasilia
Cuba ➙ heure de Cuba
Asia/Novosibirsk ➙ heure de Novossibirsk
America/Argentina/Salta ➙ heure de l’Argentine
Etc/GMT+3 ➙ UTC−03:00
Africa/Tunis ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
Etc/GMT+2 ➙ UTC−02:00
Etc/GMT+1 ➙ UTC−01:00
Pacific/Fakaofo ➙ Heure de Tokelau
Africa/Tripoli ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Est
Etc/GMT+0 ➙ heure moyenne de Greenwich
Israel ➙ heure d’Israël
Africa/Banjul ➙ Heure de Greenwich
Etc/GMT+7 ➙ UTC−07:00
Indian/Comoro ➙ Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
Etc/GMT+6 ➙ UTC−06:00
Etc/GMT+5 ➙ UTC−05:00
Etc/GMT+4 ➙ UTC−04:00
Pacific/Port_Moresby ➙ Heure de Papouasie-Nouvelle-Guinée
US/Arizona ➙ heure des Rocheuses
Antarctica/Syowa ➙ Heure de Syowa
Indian/Reunion ➙ Heure de la Réunion
Pacific/Palau ➙ Heure de Palaos
Europe/Kaliningrad ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Est
America/Montevideo ➙ heure de l’Uruguay
Africa/Windhoek ➙ Heure d'Afrique centrale
Asia/Karachi ➙ heure du Pakistan
Africa/Mogadishu ➙ Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
Australia/Perth ➙ heure de l’Ouest de l’Australie
Brazil/East ➙ heure de Brasilia
Etc/GMT ➙ heure moyenne de Greenwich
Asia/Chita ➙ heure de Iakoutsk
Pacific/Easter ➙ heure de l’île de Pâques
Antarctica/Davis ➙ Heure de Davis
Antarctica/McMurdo ➙ heure de la Nouvelle-Zélande
Asia/Macao ➙ heure de Chine
America/Manaus ➙ heure de l’Amazonie
Africa/Freetown ➙ Heure de Greenwich
Europe/Bucharest ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Est
Asia/Tomsk ➙ Tomsk Time
America/Argentina/Mendoza ➙ heure de l’Argentine
Asia/Macau ➙ heure de Chine
Europe/Malta ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
Mexico/BajaSur ➙ heure du Pacifique mexicain
Pacific/Tahiti ➙ Heure de Tahiti
Africa/Asmera ➙ Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
Europe/Busingen ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos ➙ heure de l’Argentine
Africa/Malabo ➙ heure d’Afrique de l’Ouest
Europe/Skopje ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
America/Catamarca ➙ heure de l’Argentine
America/Godthab ➙ heure de l’Ouest du Groenland
Europe/Sarajevo ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
Australia/ACT ➙ heure de l’Est de l’Australie
GB-Eire ➙ Heure britannique
Africa/Lagos ➙ heure d’Afrique de l’Ouest
America/Cordoba ➙ heure de l’Argentine
Europe/Rome ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
Asia/Dacca ➙ heure du Bangladesh
Indian/Mauritius ➙ heure de Maurice
Pacific/Samoa ➙ heure des Samoa
America/Regina ➙ heure du Centre
America/Fort_Wayne ➙ heure de l’Est
America/Dawson_Creek ➙ heure des Rocheuses
Africa/Algiers ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
Europe/Mariehamn ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Est
America/St_Johns ➙ heure de Terre-Neuve
America/St_Thomas ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
Europe/Zurich ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
America/Anguilla ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
Asia/Dili ➙ Heure de Timor-Leste
America/Denver ➙ heure des Rocheuses
Africa/Bamako ➙ Heure de Greenwich
Europe/Saratov ➙ Saratov Time
GB ➙ Heure britannique
Mexico/General ➙ heure du Centre
Pacific/Wallis ➙ Heure de Wallis-et-Futuna
Europe/Gibraltar ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
Africa/Conakry ➙ Heure de Greenwich
Africa/Lubumbashi ➙ Heure d'Afrique centrale
Asia/Istanbul ➙ Heure d'Europe de l'Est
America/Havana ➙ heure de Cuba
NZ-CHAT ➙ heure des îles Chatham
Asia/Choibalsan ➙ heure d’Oulan-Bator
America/Porto_Acre ➙ heure de l’Acre
Asia/Omsk ➙ heure d’Omsk
Europe/Vaduz ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
US/Michigan ➙ heure de l’Est
Asia/Dhaka ➙ heure du Bangladesh
America/Barbados ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
Europe/Tiraspol ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Est
Atlantic/Cape_Verde ➙ heure du Cap-Vert
Asia/Yekaterinburg ➙ heure d’Ekaterinbourg
America/Louisville ➙ heure de l’Est
Pacific/Johnston ➙ heure d’Hawaï-Aléoutiennes
Pacific/Chatham ➙ heure des îles Chatham
Europe/Ljubljana ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
America/Sao_Paulo ➙ heure de Brasilia
Asia/Jayapura ➙ Heure d'Indonésie orientale
America/Curacao ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
Asia/Dushanbe ➙ Heure du Tadjikistan
America/Guyana ➙ Heure de Guyana
America/Guayaquil ➙ Heure de l'Equateur
America/Martinique ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
Portugal ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Ouest
Europe/Berlin ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
Europe/Moscow ➙ heure de Moscou
Europe/Chisinau ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Est
America/Puerto_Rico ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
America/Rankin_Inlet ➙ heure du Centre
Pacific/Ponape ➙ Ponape
Europe/Stockholm ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
Europe/Budapest ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
America/Argentina/Jujuy ➙ heure de l’Argentine
Australia/Eucla ➙ heure du centre-ouest de l’Australie
Asia/Shanghai ➙ heure de Chine
Universal ➙ Temps universel coordonné
Europe/Zagreb ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
America/Port_of_Spain ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
Europe/Helsinki ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Est
Asia/Beirut ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Est
Asia/Tel_Aviv ➙ heure d’Israël
Pacific/Bougainville ➙ Bougainville Time
US/Central ➙ heure du Centre
Africa/Sao_Tome ➙ Heure de Greenwich
Indian/Chagos ➙ Heure de l'océan Indien
America/Cayenne ➙ Heure de Guyane française
Asia/Yakutsk ➙ heure de Iakoutsk
Pacific/Galapagos ➙ Heure des Galapagos
Australia/North ➙ heure du centre de l’Australie
Europe/Paris ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
Africa/Ndjamena ➙ heure d’Afrique de l’Ouest
Pacific/Fiji ➙ heure des îles Fidji
America/Rainy_River ➙ heure du Centre
Indian/Maldives ➙ Heure des Maldives
Australia/Yancowinna ➙ heure du centre de l’Australie
SystemV/AST4 ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
Asia/Oral ➙ Heure d'Oral
America/Yellowknife ➙ heure des Rocheuses
Pacific/Enderbury ➙ Heure de l'Ile de Phoenix
America/Juneau ➙ heure de l’Alaska
Australia/Victoria ➙ heure de l’Est de l’Australie
America/Indiana/Vevay ➙ heure de l’Est
Asia/Tashkent ➙ heure de l’Ouzbékistan
Asia/Jakarta ➙ Heure de l'Indonésie occidentale
Africa/Ceuta ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
Asia/Barnaul ➙ Barnaul Time
America/Recife ➙ heure de Brasilia
America/Buenos_Aires ➙ heure de l’Argentine
America/Noronha ➙ heure de Fernando de Noronha
America/Swift_Current ➙ heure du Centre
Australia/Adelaide ➙ heure du centre de l’Australie
America/Metlakatla ➙ heure de l’Alaska
Africa/Djibouti ➙ Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
America/Paramaribo ➙ Heure du Surinam
Asia/Qostanay ➙ Kostanay Time
Europe/Simferopol ➙ heure de Moscou
Europe/Sofia ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Est
Africa/Nouakchott ➙ Heure de Greenwich
Europe/Prague ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
America/Indiana/Vincennes ➙ heure de l’Est
Antarctica/Mawson ➙ Heure de Mawson
America/Kralendijk ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
Antarctica/Troll ➙ Troll Time
Europe/Samara ➙ heure de Samara
Indian/Christmas ➙ Heure de l'Ile Christmas
America/Antigua ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
Pacific/Gambier ➙ Heure de Gambi
America/Indianapolis ➙ heure de l’Est
America/Inuvik ➙ heure des Rocheuses
America/Iqaluit ➙ heure de l’Est
Pacific/Funafuti ➙ Heure de Tuvalu
UTC ➙ Temps universel coordonné
Antarctica/Macquarie ➙ Heure de l'Ile Macquarie
Canada/Pacific ➙ heure du Pacifique
America/Moncton ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
Africa/Gaborone ➙ Heure d'Afrique centrale
Pacific/Chuuk ➙ Heure de Chuuk
Asia/Pyongyang ➙ heure de la Corée
America/St_Vincent ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
Asia/Gaza ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Est
Etc/Universal ➙ Temps universel coordonné
PST8PDT ➙ heure du Pacifique
Atlantic/Faeroe ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Ouest
Asia/Qyzylorda ➙ Heure de Kyzylorda
Canada/Newfoundland ➙ heure de Terre-Neuve
America/Kentucky/Louisville ➙ heure de l’Est
America/Yakutat ➙ heure de l’Alaska
Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh ➙ Heure d'Indochine
Antarctica/Casey ➙ heure de l’Ouest de l’Australie
Europe/Copenhagen ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
Africa/Asmara ➙ Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
Atlantic/Azores ➙ heure des Açores
Europe/Vienna ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
ROK ➙ heure de la Corée
Pacific/Pitcairn ➙ Pitcairn
America/Mazatlan ➙ heure du Pacifique mexicain
Australia/Queensland ➙ heure de l’Est de l’Australie
Pacific/Nauru ➙ Heure de Nauru
Europe/Tirane ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
Asia/Kolkata ➙ Inde
SystemV/MST7 ➙ heure des Rocheuses
Australia/Canberra ➙ heure de l’Est de l’Australie
MET ➙ MET
Australia/Broken_Hill ➙ heure du centre de l’Australie
Europe/Riga ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Est
America/Dominica ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
Africa/Abidjan ➙ Heure de Greenwich
America/Mendoza ➙ heure de l’Argentine
America/Santarem ➙ heure de Brasilia
Kwajalein ➙ Heure des Iles Marshall
America/Asuncion ➙ heure du Paraguay
Asia/Ulan_Bator ➙ heure d’Oulan-Bator
NZ ➙ heure de la Nouvelle-Zélande
America/Boise ➙ heure des Rocheuses
Australia/Currie ➙ heure de l’Est de l’Australie
EST5EDT ➙ heure de l’Est
Pacific/Guam ➙ Chamorro
Pacific/Wake ➙ Heure de Wake
Atlantic/Bermuda ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
America/Costa_Rica ➙ heure du Centre
America/Dawson ➙ heure du Pacifique
Asia/Chongqing ➙ heure de Chine
Eire ➙ Heure irlandaise
Europe/Amsterdam ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
America/Indiana/Knox ➙ heure du Centre
America/North_Dakota/Beulah ➙ heure du Centre
Africa/Accra ➙ Heure du Ghana
Atlantic/Faroe ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Ouest
Mexico/BajaNorte ➙ heure du Pacifique
America/Maceio ➙ heure de Brasilia
Etc/UCT ➙ Temps universel coordonné
Pacific/Apia ➙ heure d’Apia
GMT0 ➙ heure moyenne de Greenwich
America/Atka ➙ heure d’Hawaï-Aléoutiennes
Pacific/Niue ➙ Heure de Niue
Australia/Lord_Howe ➙ heure de Lord Howe
Europe/Dublin ➙ Heure irlandaise
Pacific/Truk ➙ Heure de Chuuk
MST7MDT ➙ heure des Rocheuses
America/Monterrey ➙ heure du Centre
America/Nassau ➙ heure de l’Est
America/Jamaica ➙ heure de l’Est
Asia/Bishkek ➙ Heure du Kirghizistan
America/Atikokan ➙ heure de l’Est
Atlantic/Stanley ➙ heure des îles Malouines
Australia/NSW ➙ heure de l’Est de l’Australie
US/Hawaii ➙ heure d’Hawaï-Aléoutiennes
SystemV/CST6 ➙ heure du Centre
Indian/Mahe ➙ Heure des Seychelles
Asia/Aqtobe ➙ Heure d'Aqtobe
America/Sitka ➙ heure de l’Alaska
Asia/Vladivostok ➙ heure de Vladivostok
Africa/Libreville ➙ heure d’Afrique de l’Ouest
Africa/Maputo ➙ Heure d'Afrique centrale
Zulu ➙ Temps universel coordonné
America/Kentucky/Monticello ➙ heure de l’Est
Africa/El_Aaiun ➙ Heure d'Europe de l'Ouest
Africa/Ouagadougou ➙ Heure de Greenwich
America/Coral_Harbour ➙ heure de l’Est
Pacific/Marquesas ➙ Heure des Marquises
Brazil/West ➙ heure de l’Amazonie
America/Aruba ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
America/North_Dakota/Center ➙ heure du Centre
America/Cayman ➙ heure de l’Est
Asia/Ulaanbaatar ➙ heure d’Oulan-Bator
Asia/Baghdad ➙ heure de l’Arabie
Europe/San_Marino ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
America/Indiana/Tell_City ➙ heure du Centre
America/Tijuana ➙ heure du Pacifique
Pacific/Saipan ➙ Chamorro
SystemV/YST9 ➙ Alaska
Africa/Douala ➙ heure d’Afrique de l’Ouest
America/Chihuahua ➙ heure du Pacifique mexicain
America/Ojinaga ➙ heure des Rocheuses
Asia/Hovd ➙ heure de Hovd
America/Anchorage ➙ heure de l’Alaska
Chile/EasterIsland ➙ heure de l’île de Pâques
America/Halifax ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
Antarctica/Rothera ➙ Heure de Rothera
America/Indiana/Indianapolis ➙ heure de l’Est
US/Mountain ➙ heure des Rocheuses
Asia/Damascus ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Est
America/Argentina/San_Luis ➙ heure de l’Argentine
America/Santiago ➙ heure du Chili
Asia/Baku ➙ heure de l’Azerbaïdjan
America/Argentina/Ushuaia ➙ heure de l’Argentine
Atlantic/Reykjavik ➙ Heure de Greenwich
Africa/Brazzaville ➙ heure d’Afrique de l’Ouest
Africa/Porto-Novo ➙ heure d’Afrique de l’Ouest
America/La_Paz ➙ Heure de Bolivie
Antarctica/DumontDUrville ➙ Heure de Dumont-d'Urville
Asia/Taipei ➙ heure de Taipei
Antarctica/South_Pole ➙ heure de la Nouvelle-Zélande
Asia/Manila ➙ heure des Philippines
Asia/Bangkok ➙ Heure d'Indochine
Africa/Dar_es_Salaam ➙ Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
Poland ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
Atlantic/Madeira ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Ouest
Antarctica/Palmer ➙ Heure du Chili
America/Thunder_Bay ➙ heure de l’Est
Africa/Addis_Ababa ➙ Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
Asia/Yangon ➙ Heure de Myanmar
Europe/Uzhgorod ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Est
Brazil/DeNoronha ➙ heure de Fernando de Noronha
Asia/Ashkhabad ➙ heure du Turkménistan
Etc/Zulu ➙ Temps universel coordonné
America/Indiana/Marengo ➙ heure de l’Est
America/Creston ➙ heure des Rocheuses
America/Punta_Arenas ➙ Punta Arenas Time
America/Mexico_City ➙ heure du Centre
Antarctica/Vostok ➙ Heure de Vostok
Asia/Jerusalem ➙ heure d’Israël
Europe/Andorra ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
US/Samoa ➙ heure des Samoa
PRC ➙ heure de Chine
Asia/Vientiane ➙ Heure d'Indochine
Pacific/Kiritimati ➙ Heure de l'Ile de Line
America/Matamoros ➙ heure du Centre
America/Blanc-Sablon ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
Asia/Riyadh ➙ heure de l’Arabie
Iceland ➙ Heure de Greenwich
Pacific/Pohnpei ➙ Ponape
Asia/Ujung_Pandang ➙ Heure d'Indonésie centrale
Atlantic/South_Georgia ➙ Géorgie du Sud
Europe/Lisbon ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Ouest
Asia/Harbin ➙ heure de Chine
Europe/Oslo ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
Asia/Novokuznetsk ➙ heure de Krasnoïarsk
CST6CDT ➙ heure du Centre
Atlantic/Canary ➙ heure d’Europe de l’Ouest
America/Knox_IN ➙ heure du Centre
Asia/Kuwait ➙ heure de l’Arabie
SystemV/HST10 ➙ heure d’Hawaï-Aléoutiennes
Pacific/Efate ➙ heure du Vanuatu
Africa/Lome ➙ Heure de Greenwich
America/Bogota ➙ heure de Colombie
America/Menominee ➙ heure du Centre
America/Adak ➙ heure d’Hawaï-Aléoutiennes
Pacific/Norfolk ➙ heure de l’île Norfolk
Europe/Kirov ➙ Kirov Time
America/Resolute ➙ heure du Centre
Pacific/Tarawa ➙ Heure de Kiribati
Africa/Kampala ➙ Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
Asia/Krasnoyarsk ➙ heure de Krasnoïarsk
Greenwich ➙ Heure de Greenwich
SystemV/EST5 ➙ heure de l’Est
America/Edmonton ➙ heure des Rocheuses
Europe/Podgorica ➙ heure d’Europe centrale
Australia/South ➙ heure du centre de l’Australie
Canada/Central ➙ heure du Centre
Africa/Bujumbura ➙ Heure d'Afrique centrale
America/Santo_Domingo ➙ heure de l’Atlantique
… (too many to display on a Stack Overflow page)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a map of key value pairs to map the custom names that you want to the standard names expected by the library.
Since many places will be mapped to a one timezone object you can refer this site http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html