# how i can match timeZone name which is obtain from Api and timeZone name find by system in C#

Tags: c#

After passing *latitude =-17.6509195 and long=-149.42604210000002* in time zone API. I got Time Zone Name = "`Tahiti`" Time but when I pass this Time Zone Name in the C# method.

Time Zone Info . Find System Time Zone By Id(Time Zone Name);

It show an Exception :

```
 "The time zone ID 'Tahiti Time' was not found on the local computer."
```

so how can I resolve this exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TimeZone Not Found Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36838663/timezone-not-found-exception)

Answer (score 0):

`TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById` expects a standard name like "China Standard Time", the time zone name "Tahiti" is not a standard name. You can do a partial match against the standard name, though. Like this

```
ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> timeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();

foreach (TimeZoneInfo timeZone in timeZones)
{
    if (timeZone.StandardName.Contains("Tahiti"))
    {
        //You have got the timezone
        break;
    }
}
```

By the way, I try to get all the time zones on Windows 10 (1703), and I find there is no `Tahiti` timezone, Tahiti seems to belong to Pacific Timezone.