# An unhandled error has occured Maui Blazor on physical iphone

Tags: c#, ios, windows, visual-studio, maui-blazor

I successful Debug my Maui Blazor to local device which an iPhone (usb cable), However when i click into my app i got an error "An unhandled error has occured. Reload". How can I see the output of the error.
Im using visual studio 22 for windows
Thanks

i tried chrome://inspect/#devices but it does not show my iphone to inspect. here is the code in the index.razor

```
        @if (dataObjects is not null)
        {

            @foreach (var product in dataObjects)
            {
                @if (@product.Sl.HasValue)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>Số Lượng: @product.Sl</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tiền Mặt: @Math.Round(product.TienMat.Value, 2).ToString("n2")</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Thẻ:
                            @if (@product.The.HasValue)
                                @Math.Round(product.The.Value, 2).ToString("n2")


                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> Lợi Nhuận: @Math.Round(product.LoiNhuan.Value, 2).ToString("n2")</td>
                    </tr>
                }


            }
        }

<button @onclick="OnRefreshClicked">Refresh</button>

@code {
    private List<ThongTinBanHangTrongNgay> dataObjects;
    private HttpClient client;
    private UltiHelps ultiHelps;

    private async Task OnRefreshClicked()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");
        DateTime australianNow = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, zone);
        String TodayDate = australianNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("XXXXX");
        //string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        // Khi dữ liệu được trả về, hãy sử dụng phương thức JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() để chuyển đổi dữ liệu JSON thành một đối tượng DataTable
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dataObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ThongTinBanHangTrongNgay>>(json);
            //dataObjects._products = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DataTable>(json);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ```However when i click into my app i got an error```  Do you mean clicking a button? Could you please share some relevant code or provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Did your project work on a iOS simulator?

Comment: You may try creating a default new maui blazor project and see if it works on a physical iphone.

Comment: Hi, I have added the code. the project works fine  on windows and android, only on ios i got that error when i click to the button on my app and I could not find the way to see the error output. I do not use ios simulator cause i do not have mac.

Comment: So you use [Hot restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/hot-restart)? Hot restart has some [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/hot-restart#limitations). For debugging, you may reduce your code step by step to find which line caused this crash.

Comment: yes, i use hot restart . So is there any chance to get the error output ?

Comment: Have you tried using a [Exception-handling statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/exception-handling-statements) for possible code?

Comment: yah, its acctualy i can put breakpoint to test. the error in this line
TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");

Comment: Hello, you could try using IANA time zones. Please try the solution in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue. The error should be 'The time zone ID 'AUS Eastern Standard Time' was not found on the local computer'. It only happens on iOS.

The workaround is, if Windows time zones don't work, you may try using IANA time zones.

So if you use **Australia/Melbourne** or **Australia/Sydney**

```
TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Australia/Melbourne");
```

Then it works fine.

For more info, you could refer to [Converting Microsoft Timezone to standards timezone data in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30795167/20118901) and [How to translate between Windows and IANA time zones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348807/how-to-translate-between-windows-and-iana-time-zones).

Hope it helps!