# Java Time: Convert Time Zone Name (Window Time Zone Name) to java supported Time zone Id (TimeZone)

Tags: java, time, timezone

I am writing a Java program. I only have a list of time zone names and I wanted to convert this in Java Time API supported Zone ID

For example, I want to convert following list

```
US Eastern Standard Time
Central Standard Time
```

into the below list
US\EST
US\Centeral

My ultimate goal is to have TimeZone object using the windows time zone name

Comment: The fundamental issue is that the names you mention do **not** directly map to unique Olson IDs. The names you use more closely map to zone rule names, which can apply to any given Time Zone ID at *some time*, but not at others.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: It's a bit weirder than that - Windows uses "US Eastern Standard Time" to refer to Eastern time zones *including in DST*. It's a bizarre kind of ID, but that's what Windows has decided to do :( See the info in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezoneinfo for more details.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I ... did not know that. Having dealt with timezones way to much on Android I thought I knew all the nasty little details, but that's beyond what I expected.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: First rule of time zones: there are *always* more nasty little details. (The two I'm particularly fond of are Ireland observing negative DST, and the Japanese transitions at "25:00" from 1948 to 1951.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: my favorite is `Antarctica/Troll` having two different daylights saving time offsets (i.e. 3 total offsets) during the year and most libraries just politely ignoring that fact, because it would mess up everything.

Comment: You need to use the [CLDR Windows zones](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/master/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml) for conversions. Try the ICU4J method [`TimeZone.getIDForWindowsID`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/TimeZone.html#getIDForWindowsID-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to translate between windows and IANA timezones in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450236/how-to-translate-between-windows-and-iana-timezones-in-java)