# Getting Timezone info issue on AWS Lambda C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So I was trying to get timezone info by id in lambda application. It is working fine on the local machine, but it throws an error when I publish on aws lambda.

TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(Common.NotifyTimeZone);

NotifyTimeZone value is "Pacific Standard Time"

The exception is "The time zone ID 'Pacific Standard Time' was not found on the local computer"

Comment: Your local machine is windows machine?

Comment: What versions of .Net are being used - local and AWS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41566395/timezoneinfo-in-net-core-when-hosting-on-unix-nginx

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/cross-platform-time-zones-with-net-core/

Comment: @phuzi I am using net core 2.1

Comment: @phuzi I don't think so. Before posting here, I searched for all the possible solutions on google. The link you shared has a different issue. I am having an issue with amazon web services Lambda.

Comment: The AWS lambda runs on Linux. And Linux does not have timezones info available the same way it's available in windows machine. That's why you are getting error on lambda. Please read the links mentioned in the comments to understand it better. The links also have solution around it.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Oh okay.

Comment: AWS Lambdas run on Amazon Linux. What about that is not relevant? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html