# Could not convert utc time to specific time zone

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I have deployed my asp.net core application in **azure linux**. I am trying to convert UTC time to 'Central Europe Standard Time'.
But, I am getting the following exception. In my local no issues, but I am getting issue after deployment.

> The time zone ID 'Central Europe Standard Time' was not found on the
> local computer. Could not find file '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Central
> Europe Standard Time'.

```
TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Europe Standard Time");
   var cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, cstZone);
```

Comment: That timezone is a windows specific thing, you need to use the IANA name.

Comment: Please also be careful with `Central European Standard Time` vs `Central Europe Standard Time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux and Windows store timzones differently (see for example [TimeZoneInfo in .NET Core when hosting on unix (nginx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41566395/timezoneinfo-in-net-core-when-hosting-on-unix-nginx)).

One solution is to examine what is available and choose appropriately like shown at [How to get TimeZoneInfo on Windows and Linux](https://www.ankursheel.com/blog/get-time-zone-info-windows-linux) from [www.ankursheel.com](http://www.ankursheel.com):

> ```
> var nzTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Any(x => x.Id == "New Zealand Standard Time")
>    ? TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("New Zealand Standard Time")
>    : TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific/Auckland");
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, your answer is right. I have used the following to convert datetime. https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneConverter

Answer (score 2):

For the App Services that run on Linux, you should use Time Zone values from the IANA TZ database.

In your case Time Zone `Central Europe Standard Time` in linux could be `Europe/Amsterdam`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-configuration-and-management#how-do-i-set-the-server-time-zone-for-my-web-app

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, your answer is right. I have used the following to convert datetime. https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneConverter