# Convert IANA timezones to Windows timezones in C++

Tags: c++

At the moment I am working on an windows application which should set the Windows System Timezone. 
Sadly the timezone is given in IANA format. (e.g. Europe/Berlin).

Do you know any C or C++ solution to convert the IANA format timezone in a Windows Timezone so i can set it as new System timezone?

For example:

I have "Europe/Berlin"

and i need:

(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna

W. Europe Standard Time

Comment: I wonder if Boost has it.

Comment: This one is for C#, but maybe it can help you get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348807/how-to-translate-between-windows-and-iana-time-zones

Comment: Here's the opposite mapping.  You might be able to modify it to do what you want: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/src/tz.cpp#L486-L509