# Trying to map a Microsoft Windows BCL Zone to a Tzdb zone for access to its abbreviation values

Tags: nodatime

I'm looking for a way to map a BCL Time Zone value to a Tzdb Time Zone value to get the more expressive values exposed by Tzdb:

For example, I can get BCL time zone as follows. The `incomingValue` variable is a Microsoft Windows name for the zone, for example `Pacific Standard Time` from https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/973627/microsoft-time-zone-index-values :

```
 var bclZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl.GetZoneOrNull(incomingValue); // ok - it works
```

Next, what is the best way to then get an equivalent Tzdb zone value (or zones)?  I've been fiddling with the following code to no avail.

```
// The Tzdb provider won't accept a BCL zone value or a Microsoft zone name.
 DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull(.. ? ..);
```

The reason I'm asking for this conversion is because the Tzdb zone is more expressive containing abbreviations that can be employed in a tight display scenario, whereas I cannot find abbreviations or other rich values associated with the Microsoft BCL zone type. 
I'd rather use the Tzdb values than do a manual mapping because I think between these two zone providers they contain everything I need 'out of the box'.

I'm also mulling over using a UTC -/+ calculation to transition to the Tzdb value but am asking here if there is a better approach with noda.

Comment: I'm well aware of the `Avoid abbrevations if you possibly can` stipulations because of inherent ambiguities, but have a valid business case for them. https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/nodatime/ re: Time Zone Issue

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348807 - is it? Note that you can use `TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.WindowsMapping` to get at Windows mapping information within Noda Time as well. (I haven't marked it as a duplicate because I'm unsure.)

Comment: You're right. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. This question is effectively a delicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/17348807/179972

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to translate between Windows and IANA time zones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348807/how-to-translate-between-windows-and-iana-time-zones)