# Timezone Name Conversion Between SQL Server and Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql-server, datetime, timezone

I have some data that I want to report on (simplified for brevity):

```
MyDateTime (UTC)     MyValue
------               -------
2020-10-01 10:00:00  24
2020-10-01 15:00:00  53
2020-10-02 12:00:00  26
etc
```

All dates are stored as UTC. Normally, I would keep everything in UTC for as long as possible, and convert to the local time in the users browser based on the users locale.

However for this particular report, I want to aggregate the data by whole dates:

```
SELECT CAST(MyDateTime AS DATE), AVG(MyValue)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY CAST(MyDateTime AS DATE)
```

So I need to convert the date to the user's local time before I truncate the `MyDateTime` column and aggregate it.

In SQL Server, I can convert the UTC `datetime` to a local truncated date like this:

```
CAST(CONVERT(datetime2, (SeizeTime AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time'), 1) AS DATE)
```

SQL Server has a list of timezone names that the `AT TIME ZONE` clause accepts, in my example I'm using `GMT Standard Time` which is UK time including daylight savings.

Javascript running in a browser has another way of naming timezones:

```
console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone)
--> Europe/London
```

So my problem is that there is no common way of naming timezones between SQL Server and Javascript. How can I reliably map `Europe/London` to `GMT Standard Time`, along with all the other possible timezones in the world?

My options to get around this so far are:

- Use a hard-coded lookup table - *could break if timezone info changes in the future.*
- Send all the pre-aggregated data to the browser, apply the timezone to the date and then aggregate the data on the client - *I want to avoid moving too much data around unnecessarily.*

Is there any other way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: on client side using var date = new Date('2012-11-29 17:00:34 UTC');
date.toString(); will be in the local time of the client who is using the page

Comment: @sandeepjoshi Thanks, but how do I pull the timezone info out of the browser, send it to the server, and use it in SQL Server to do the aggregation I asked about in my question?

Comment: sorry i thought you want to do it on client side. I guess mapping the lookup table will be good idea but i guess in older browsers and IE11 do not support it :( . if you convert date using time difference with GMT then I guess you can send `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60` which will give you difference in timezone in number of hours. -ve value indicates countries ahead of GMT and positive are behind.

Comment: @sandeepjoshi Another good idea, but the problem is that `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60` will give you the timezone offset at that moment in time. I'm looking to query historical data that could cross a Daylight savings boundary.

Comment: How are you *connecting* to SQL Server?  Do you have an application layer? Is it .NET, Node.JS, something else?

Answer (score 2):

*Given the history of questions in your user profile, I'll assume you are using .NET in your application layer to query your SQL Server.  If this is not the case, please comment and I will adjust my answer accordingly.*

The core of your question is addressed by [*How to translate between Windows and IANA time zones?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348807/how-to-translate-between-windows-and-iana-time-zones).  In short, you can use my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library in your application layer to convert the IANA time zone name coming from `Intl` in the browser, to a Windows time zone name that SQL Server will recognize.

However, I'll also add a few points on the SQL part of your question:

- In many cases, you're better off doing time zone conversions in your application layer than in SQL Server.  .NET's `TimeZoneInfo` class can handle the conversions and understands IANA identifiers when running on Linux.  You can use `TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo` from TimeZoneConverter to work with them when running on Windows.  (Or alternatively, you could use [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) for the conversions.)
- If you are working with a relatively small number of data points, query them all from SQL *without grouping*, then in your application layer convert them and then group and perform the aggregations there.  That will come with memory and network overhead - but will make your queries more efficient and conversions easier.
- If you are working with a larger data set, then the aggregation and conversion indeed must be done at query time.  Use `TZConvert.IanaToWindows` from TimeZoneConverter, and pass that as a parameter to your query to be used with `AT TIME ZONE`.
- To prevent the query engine having to scan the entire table, you'll want an index over your UTC value.  You'll also want a `WHERE` clause that uses that raw value, so your query is ["sargable"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799584/634824).  Thus, you'll need to convert the desired query range from the client's time zone to UTC *before* executing the query.
- When the source value is a `datetime` or `datetime2`, you need to use `AT TIME ZONE` *twice*.  For example `SomeDateTimeValue AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'`.  The first will create a `datetimeoffset` using the time zone given, assigning the correct offset (`+00:00`) while keeping the date and time values.  The second will convert that `datetimeoffset` to another `datetimeoffset` in the given time zone, adjusting the date, time, and offset accordingly.

Here is an example to demonstrate the SQL side of things.  I've set up a temp table with some additional values to make clear what is included and excluded from the final query.

```sql
--Temp table for demo purposes
CREATE TABLE #MyTable (UtcDateTime datetime2, MyValue int)
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES ('2020-10-01 06:00:00', 1000) -- excluded
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES ('2020-10-01 07:00:00', 100)  -- included
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES ('2020-10-01 10:00:00', 24)   -- included
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES ('2020-10-01 15:00:00', 53)   -- included
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES ('2020-10-02 12:00:00', 26)   -- included
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES ('2020-10-03 06:00:00', 100)  -- included
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES ('2020-10-03 07:00:00', 1000) -- excluded
 
-- These are the input values of the query
DECLARE @ClientTZ varchar(50) = 'Pacific Standard Time' -- Converted from 'America/Los_Angeles' in the application layer with TimeZoneConverter
DECLARE @FromClientDate date  = '2020-10-01'
DECLARE @ToClientDate date = '2020-10-02'


-- START OF QUERY

-- First you'll need to know the UTC datetimes of the range you are querying over.
-- This pair of values creates a half-open UTC datetime range to be used in the WHERE clause below.
DECLARE @FromUtcDateTime datetime2 = CAST(@FromClientDate AS datetime2) AT TIME ZONE @ClientTZ AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
DECLARE @ToUtcDateTime datetime2 = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, @ToClientDate) AS datetime2) AT TIME ZONE @ClientTZ AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'

-- Now you can do the query.  The inner subquery does the filtering and conversion.  The outer query does the aggregation.
SELECT ClientDate, AVG(MyValue) as AvgValue
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(UtcDateTime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE @ClientTZ AS date) as ClientDate, MyValue
    FROM #MyTable
    WHERE UtcDateTime >= @FromUtcDateTime AND UtcDateTime < @ToUtcDateTime
) q
GROUP BY q.ClientDate

-- END OF QUERY

-- Drop the temp table for demo cleanup
DROP TABLE #MyTable
```