# The time zone ID 'Central Daylight Time' was not found on the local computer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using a javascript snippet to get the timezone name of the user.
Here is the snippet

```js
function getTimezoneName() {
    const today = new Date();
    const short = today.toLocaleDateString(undefined);
    const full = today.toLocaleDateString(undefined, { timeZoneName: 'long' });

    // Trying to remove date from the string in a locale-agnostic way
    const shortIndex = full.indexOf(short);
    if (shortIndex >= 0) {
        const trimmed = full.substring(0, shortIndex) + full.substring(shortIndex + short.length);

        // by this time `trimmed` should be the timezone's name with some punctuation -
        // trim it from both sides
        return trimmed.replace(/^[\s,.\-:;]+|[\s,.\-:;]+$/g, '');

    } else {
        // in some magic case when short representation of date is not present in the long one, just return the long one as a fallback, since it should contain the timezone's name
        return full;
    }
}

console.log(getTimezoneName());
```

After getting the timezone of the user I am saving it to the database for timezone conversion purposes. This solution was working fine before the "Central Daylight Time" timezone Id.
I was taking the user timezone from the database and converting the UTC time to user's timezone using [FindSystemTimeZoneById](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_TimeZoneInfo_FindSystemTimeZoneById_System_String_).

Here is my extension method:

```
public static DateTime ToClientTime(this DateTime dt)
    {
        var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(HttpContext.Current.User.GetTimeZone());
        var tzTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt, tz);
        return tzTime;
    }
```

Now, the issue is javascript snippet is showing me the timezone id "Central Daylight Time" but in the timezones provided [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms912391(v=winembedded.11)) there is no key with this name.

Can anyone provide me the solution for this issue.

Comment: Central Daylight Time is what Central Standard Time is called during daylight savings. Similar for other zones. You might need to find/replace Daylight=>Standard

Comment: Is this a proper solution for this issue?

Comment: Because there are 140 timezone keys and there are 130 with `Standard`.

Comment: Maybe related to Windows/IANA(Linux) naming difference, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348807/how-to-translate-between-windows-and-iana-time-zones