# How to get UTC offset from Microsoft Graph API's timezone value returned from /me/mailboxSettings/timeZone?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, microsoft-graph-api, nodatime

I'm using the `/me/mailboxSettings/timeZone` Graph API to get a user's timezone information.

In attempt to figure out the expected return result format, I came across this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/datetimetimezone?view=graph-rest-1.0

So it seems MS Graph's supported timezones are a mixture of Windows and IANA timezones.

But there is no doc that mentions what kind of timezone one should expect when calling the `/me/mailboxSettings/timeZone` API.

Does this mean I should expect to encounter both IANA and Windows timezones when calling this API?

If that is the case, is there a quick method to use this info to get the current UTC offset from the timezone, when the timezone could be in **either** Windows **or** IANA format at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation on [get mailbox settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) graph will support both IANA and Windows Timezones depending on the mailbox configuration. There are some questions on how to convert between IANA and Windows timezones see [how-to-translate-between-windows-and-iana-time-zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348807/how-to-translate-between-windows-and-iana-time-zones) - then you can use [`TimeZoneInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo) to get the `GetUtcOffset` method.

I hope this helps,

Comment: These random feature requests will go nowhere. I'm not expecting the Graph API to return the offset, rather it will need to get done via some C#/.NET library.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I have updated the answer with more relevant info.

Comment: Thanks. Since I won't know ahead of the time if the `timeZone` MS Graph returns is Windows or IANA, do I simply do something like looking for the "/" character in the string and if yes it's IANA, or compare the string against the full list of Windows/IANA timezone DB?? It feels a bit hacky for me, unless there's a library out there that can detect the timezone type do the conversion for both.

Comment: You can use the TimeZoneConverter library mentioned in the link in this answer. Its `GetTimeZoneInfo` method will take either form. But also, don't use `BaseUtcOffset`, but rather `GetUtcOffset`.